# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id () for fragment

Tags: android, layout, fragment, sliding, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment inside a sliding pane layout.Every component has id attribute to it.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/interviewDetailsScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/candidateDetailScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/candidateSummaryFragment"
        android:name="com.ultimatix.ncp.activity.ui.NCPCandidateSummaryFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/candidateDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.ultimatix.ncp.activity.ui.NCPCandidateDetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I am replacing one of the fragments with use of FragmentTransaction.

```
ft.replace(R.id.candidateSummaryFragment, new NCPCandidateSummaryFragment());
    ft.commit();
```

But error it shows the error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0074 
for fragment NCPCandidateSummaryFragment{40decd50 #3 id=0x7f0b0074}

The R.java also has the entry regarding the fragment with same hex and id.

Comment: I do not think that fragments statically define can be replaced

Comment: Are you using ViewPager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be your current activity does not have this xml file in `setContentView()`. You must specify a view for fragment that is child of current layout of your activity.

Check `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayot)` function, I think problem is there.

Comment: thanks for replying
but its there 
setContentView(R.layout.ncp_interview_evaluation_home_layout);